# Jquery ControlGroup text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone please help me, I'm struggling to get text input from a JQuery ControlGroup to be sent through a websocket.  The issue is I can't get the text input from the editable text as an input variable that gets passed to a button action.  In the console debug I'm getting undefined for the variable passed through websocket.  How do I identify the ControlGroup div?  Here is relevant code.
    `</div>
    <pre id="page" contenteditable="true">
    Insert editable text here
    Test 1 2 3....`

```
<button type="button" onclick="sendTxt()">Send</button>
  function sendTxt()
  {
    ws.send(document.getElementById('page').value);
  }
```

Comment: This is from the source code for the jquery UI ControlGroup editor toolbar.  Only difference is WS code and having a button to send text through WS:

Comment: Use `.textContent` instead `.value`.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks a million!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I've added my comment as answer. Feel free to accept to help to others users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment.

Use `.textContent` instead `.value`.

Because the `value` attribute doesn't exist in `pre` tag.